Recursive initial segment of a nonstandard model of PA
Let $M$ be a countable nonstandard model of PA. We define a cut to be an initial segment that is closed under the successor function. In Kaye's Models of Peano Arithmetic, it is argued that for any nonstandard $a \in M \setminus \mathbb N$, the set
$$a^{1/\mathbb N} = \{x \in M \mid x^n < a\text{ for all }n \in \mathbb N\}$$
is a cut not satisfying PA. That is to say, no matter how close one gets to the first copy of $\mathbb N$ in $M$, one can find an initial segment not satisfying PA.
This makes me suspect that Tennenbaum-like behavior doesn't arise in a model if we get 'close enough to  $\mathbb N$'. To be more precise, given any countable $M\vDash \text{PA}$, can we always a subset $I\subseteq M$ such that:

$I$ is an initial segment of $M$ and $\mathbb N \subsetneq I$.
There are recursive relations $+_2,\cdot_2 \subseteq \mathbb N^3$, $ <_2\subseteq 
\mathbb N^2$ and constants $n_0, n_1$ such that
$$(\mathbb N, <_2, +_2, \cdot_2, n_0, n_1)\cong(I, <_I,  +_I, \cdot_I, 0_M, 1_M)$$
Where $+_I:= +_M \cap I\times I \times I$ and $\cdot_I = \cdot_M \cap I \times I \times I$.

And if the answer is positive, would this mean one can obtain meaningful number-theoretic results via the transfer principle, assuming such relations on $\mathbb N$ and the isomorphism $\mathbb N \to I$ could actually be computed?

In fact, this never happens.
Let $M$ be a countable nonstandard model of $\mathsf{PA}$. The standard system of $M$ is the set of sets of natural numbers which are "coded" into $M$; precisely, we let $$\mathsf{SS}(M)=\{A\subseteq\mathbb{N}:\exists x\in M\forall y\in\mathbb{N}(y\in A\iff p_y\vert x)\},$$ where $p_i$ denotes the $i$th prime. The relevant facts are:

$\mathsf{SS}(M)$ always contains a noncomputable set (indeed, $\mathsf{SS}(M)$ is always a Scott set).

Each element $A\in\mathsf{SS}(M)$ is "witnessed as early as desired," i.e. for all $a\in M\setminus \mathbb{N}$ there is some $b<a$ such that $A=\{y\in\mathbb{N}: p_y\vert b\}$.


These are each cute applications of overspill. For the former, let $T$ be an infinite computable subtree of $2^{<\mathbb{N}}$ with no computable infinite paths; then the version of $T$ in $M$ has a node of nonstandard length, and this node yields an element of $M$ coding a path through $T$. For the second, suppose $A,a$ falsified the claim; then we can define $\mathbb{N}$ in $M$ from $a$ by saying that $n$ is standard iff there is a number $b<a$ such that for each $k<n$ we have $p_k\vert b\iff p_k\vert c$, where $c$ is some fixed number in $M$ coding $A$.
This means that no matter what initial segment $I$ we pick, there will be an $i\in I$ which codes a noncomputable set $A$, and the decoding process $i\leadsto A$ is computable relative to the arithmetic operations of $M$ restricted to $I$.

Thank you! This is just as harrowing (yet fascinating) as Tennenbaum's original result, if not more.
